# Python - How can I create a trail/trace behind an movable object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to create a line or a dashed line behind my moving object to look like a trail. But my code create only one small line on the same spot and that's it. Do you know what I have to do to work like a trail?
This is my code (I think the problem is how I create the line in the "on_key_press" function):

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()  # Create a window
window.title("Comanda manuala")  # Set a title
width = 1240
height = 640

x = 550
y = 525
canvas = Canvas(window, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()

c1 = canvas.create_oval(x - 10, y + 10, x + 10, y - 10, fill='black')

left, right, up, down = -5, 5, -5, 5


def on_key_press(event):
    x2 = 0
    y2 = 0
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        x2 = left
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x - 5, y, tags="line")
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        x2 = right
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x + 5, y, tags="line")
    elif event.keysym == "Up":
        y2 = up
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x, y - 5, tags="line")
    elif event.keysym == "Down":
        y2 = down
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x, y + 5, tags="line")
    canvas.move(c1, x2, y2)


window.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you could reduce this code down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is with creating a "trail/trace" behind a movable object then we probably don't need any of the code related to cv2, or any images at all, or half a dozen buttons.

Comment: Thank you, I did it. It's ok?

Comment: If by did it, you mean you solved your problem either post an answer yourself and accept the answer, or delete your question,.

Comment: Oh sorry! I mean that I did the minimal reproducible exemple. I didn't solved the problem.

Comment: You don't ever change the `x` and `y` values so obviously they will stay the same, You have to change them according to how the circle moves, so probably just increase them with Your circle coords. also if You are trying to make a game it would be way easier to just do it in `pygame` IMO

Comment: I don't want to create a game, it's for a project. I tried to change de line's coordinate according to my circle, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't update `x` and `y`, so the *trail/trace* will be always in same position.  There are two ways to update them:

1. using global variables

```py
def on_key_press(event):
    global x, y

    dx = dy = 0
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        dx = left
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        dx = right
    elif event.keysym == "Up":
        dy = up
    elif event.keysym == "Down":
        dy = down

    canvas.create_line(x, y, x+dx, y+dy, tags="line")
    canvas.move(c1, dx, dy)

    # update x and y
    x += dx
    y += dy
```

2. calculate `x` and `y` from the result of `.coords()`:

```py
def on_key_press(event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(c1)
    x, y = (x1+x2)//2, (y1+y2)//2    # center of circle

    dx = dy = 0
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        dx = left
    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        dx = right
    elif event.keysym == "Up":
        dy = up
    elif event.keysym == "Down":
        dy = down

    canvas.create_line(x, y, x+dx, y+dy, tags="line")
    canvas.move(c1, dx, dy)
```